# How to refer to high-level model from nested one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm trying to make conditional validation based on Project status in Payment model. For example status can be "Talks" or "Active". What's the best way to do it considering the structure below?

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :costs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :payments, :through => :costs, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :costs, :allow_destroy => true
end
class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments, :allow_destroy => true
  belongs_to :project
end
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cost
  validates_presence_of :value1, :if => :new?
  validates_presence_of :value1, :if => :talks?
  validates_presence_of :value2, :if => :active?

  def new?
    # if controller action is new
  end
  def talks?
    # if project status is "Talks" (edit action)
  end
  def active?
    # if project status is "Active" (edit action)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cost
  has_one :project, :through => :cost
  validates_presence_of :value1, :if => :new?
  validates_presence_of :value1, :if => :talks?
  validates_presence_of :value2, :if => :active?

  def new?
    self.new_record?
  end
  def talks?
    project.status == "talks"
  end
  def active?
    project.status == "active"
  end
end
```

Comment: project is nil this way. `undefined method 'status' for nil:NilClass`. I've added `belongs_to :project`.

Comment: it means you didn't specify project to payment.

Comment: It's working perfectly when Project just `has_many payments` and Payment has `project_id`, but doesn't seem to work if Project `has_many :payments, :through => :costs`, Cost `has_many payments` and Payment `belongs_to :cost`. I have desired result when `cost.project.status == "talks"`. However is it possible to refer to Project directly from Payment model escaping Cost model?

Comment: Got it, sorry I didn't see that `:through` option. I'll update my answer

Comment: You should use `has_one :project, :through => :cost` instead

Comment: Great! Thanks! One more question please! When editing form, let's say I have existing costs and payments. But what if I'm adding new costs and payments dynamically using js. In this case those will be blank, which means that project also will be blank (when validation will be triggered). What I should do in this situation?

Comment: I mean if project status is "active" and I've just added new payment dynamically. It will be `new?` for validation.

Comment: object will be "new?" unless it is saved